# Python - using py2exe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, py2exe

I'm trying to create an *.exe file from my Python code.

This is my `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

setup(

    options={
    'py2exe':
        {
           'includes': ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'gzip','pandas'], 
        }
    },
    data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
console=['test_zone_A_main.py'])
```

The code works fine on my machine, but when I'm running the exe on different machine , I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\company\Campaign_Analyze>"C:\Program Files (x86)\sintec\Ca
mpaign_Analyze\dist\test_zone_A_main.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_zone_A_main.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "calcs_performence.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "test_config_cs.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "pandas\__init__.pyc", line 13, in <module>
ImportError: C extension: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion of building the C extensions? When you built the EXE, did the logs specify required DLLs that were not included?